# docker failed to start in a container with dind. Error starting daemon: pid file found, ensure docker is not running or delete /var/run/docker.pid

Tags: docker, containers

I am trying to run docker-in-docker.
I am running docker in a container. After restarting the container I get the error

```
docker failed to start. In /var/log/docker.log I see the following line - Error starting daemon: pid file found, ensure docker is not running or delete /var/run/docker.pid.
Suggestion - modify run-docker.sh to delete this file before starting the docker
```

I think, the docker is already running, but it tries to start it again. Thus giving rise to this error.

My Dockerfile has ubuntu:18.04 as base image. I have installed docker in it. The entrypoint is dockerd & and server starting command.

```
CMD [ dockerd && "python3","manage.py","runserver","0.0.0.0:3608"]
```

I cannot use dind image directly as my project has some limitations.

Please help

Comment: I cannot image a project that requires dind and at the same time cannot use official docker:dind image either directly or as a base image. Could you share what exactly are you trying to accomplish? Perhaps there is a simpler way than custom dind image, which is hell to make, as you discovered.

Comment: My project uses some packages which are not compatible when I use dind image as base image. The server uses an external utility to convert pdf to html. When dockerised this utility reduces the latency to a huge extent . Thus my dockerised server used this dockerised utility.@KonradBotor

Comment: In other words you need to start another container from within your container? Do you start it using docker command or docker-py package?

Comment: Docker-in-Docker has been generally discouraged for almost as long as it's existed.  If you must use it, I'd use the embedded Docker to launch your application container inside the nested Docker.  Do not try to launch two services in the same container.

Comment: @KonradBotor I use docker command

Comment: @DavidMaze Embedded Docker as in? Could you please help me with an example or may be link to such use case

Comment: I assume he meant Docker running inside your container - as opposed to Docker running on your host.

Answer (score 0):

OP, as I understand, your app is some sort of a server, that utilizes another service and you want to dockerize the whole thing. I will list possible solutions below:

1. You can use [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) to start the external service, build the image containing your server and link the two together.

Example:

```
version:'3.3'
services:
  your-server:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3608:3608"
    depends_on:
      - utility
  utility:
    image: "external_utility_image"
```

The above assumes your `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` are in the same directory and that your `Dockerfile` describes an image that contains your server only - no docker-in-docker required. Your server would connect to the external utility using hostname `utility` (the same as service name specified in `docker-compose.yml`).

2. You can make your Python script use Docker installed on your host and [Docker SDK](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html).

Example using nginx as an external utility:

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /app
COPY ./requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY ./run.py run.py

CMD [ "/app/run.py" ]
```

`requirements.txt`:

```
docker==4.2.2
```

`run.py`:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

import docker
import urllib.request
import time

client = docker.from_env()
client.containers.run('nginx:stable-alpine', detach=True, name='service')

service = client.containers.get('service')
ip = service.attrs['NetworkSettings']['IPAddress']
print(f"Service IP: {ip}")

time.sleep(5) #Wait for service to start

with urllib.request.urlopen(f"http://{ip}") as r:
    contents = r.read()
    print(contents)

service.stop()
service.remove(v=True)
```

How to use:

```
docker build --tag docker-py-test:latest .
docker run -it --rm -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock docker-py-test:latest
```

3. Docker-in-Docker - your current approach - NOT RECOMMENDED

[Docker-in-Docker on Ubuntu 14.04 - deprecated](https://github.com/jpetazzo/dind)
[Official repository for Docker and Docker-in-Docker images](https://github.com/docker-library/docker)

4. Installing two services in the same container - NOT RECOMMENDED

In this scenario you would install your server and the external utility in the same image, rather than using premade image containing the utility. You would also need some king of supervisor process.

[Official Docker documentation for running multiple processes in a single container](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/)